# Target text without tags in a form

Tags: javascript, php, css

I am using a WordPress plugin on my website and I have a form that has some text I need to change, basically perform a find and replace. The problem is the form doesn't have a class and neither does the text, but since this is a plugin, I am not able to modify the actual plugin files. I only want to target a specific form on a specific page, so I'm wondering how to do this? I found a band-aid solution, but I'm wondering if there isn't a better way to do this?

My code looks like:

```
<?php if (is_page("tickets")) { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("form").addClass("tickets");
            
        $("form").contents().filter(function(){
            return this.nodeType === 3
        }).wrap('<p />');
            
        $("form p").text($("form p").text().replace("PayPal", ""));
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Basically, this is a WordPress website, so `is_page` is targeting the specific page that has the form on it. The JS is only executing on the "Tickets" page.

Then, I am adding a class called tickets to my form, so I can target that specific form for styling purposes. This way I'm not affecting any of my other forms site-wide :-)

I am also wrapping text without tags in p tags. This way, I can target the text without tags for JS and styling purposes.

Finally...I am targeting the text (I just wrapped in p tags) and am removing the word "PayPal".

I try and stay away from JS if I can, because I know it can slow your page speed down, but I'm thinking since I narrowed it down to a specific page and a specific form, it probably won't affect things that much.

All this JS is pieced together from code I found here and there. Is there a better way to do this

The form looks like:

```
<div>
    <form target="_blank" action="https://url.com/wp-admin/admin-post.php?action=add_wpeevent_button_redirect" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
        <input type="hidden" name="path" value="sandbox.paypal">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="seller@url.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="2022 Event Name">
        <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="20681">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
        <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://url.com/wp-admin/admin-post.php?action=add_wpeevent_button_ipn">
        <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="EN_US">
        <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="WPPlugin_SP">
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
    
        <table class="main-table_20681" style="width: 100% !important;">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="row-qty">
                        <select name="wpeevent_button_qty_a">
                            <option value="0">0</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td class="row-name">Ticket</td>
                    <td class="row-price">31.50 USD</td>
                    <td class="row-desc">
                        2022 Event Name
                        <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Ticket">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id_1" value="2201">
                        <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="31.50">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        Your eTicket will be sent to your PayPal email address after payment.<br>
        <input class="wpeevent_paypalbuttonimage" type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make your payments with PayPal. It is free, secure, effective." style="border: none;"><img loading="lazy" alt="" border="0" style="border:none;display:none;" src="https://www.paypal.com/EN_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form>
</div>
```

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: I'd use `<span>` instead of `<p>` since latter is a block element

Comment: I can do that! Thanks!! Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using @vinay suggestion...thank you @vinay!

So now, the code looks like:

```
<?php if (is_page("tickets")) { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("form").addClass("tickets");
        
        $("form").contents().filter(function(){
            return this.nodeType === 3
        }).wrap('<span />');
        
        $("form span").text($("form span").text().replace("PayPal", ""));
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```